# Extra E-mail address consistently set as Invalid

Tags: contacts, webform-civicrm

After a contact is created from a Webform (latest version on D7) used for membership with Stripe, two E-mail addresses are created:

- one, set as Main Address which corresponds to the setting of the Webform
- the other one, set as Billing Address that is set nowhere (at least I can't find it in Webform or elsewhere in CiviCRM, see bellow) and this one will be consistently set as 'Invalid'

Has anyone already faced this situation? Is it related to Stripe?

[image]

[image: List item]

Edit: [image]

Comment: what do you mean by 'invalid'?

Comment: I've seen sometimes people will add an invisible space after the email, and then everything seems to go ok at first but then about an hour later stripe rejects it as an invalid email.

Comment: the address in the contact summary is defined as 'Invalid' see image added

Comment: @Demerit I'd say I find this behaviour for almost if not all contacts. But this was a good idea to check if I hadn't left an invisible space per default in the field, which wasn't the case